# Multiple POST request is not working after submit

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I am trying to use 2 post method in a single page one is for login and other one is for contact us
login is working fine but after submitting contact us the content of login and contact us page is gone

I tried to pass various type of dictionary but still, it's not working

app/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from homePage.forms import SignInForm,DropUsaMessage
# Create your views here.
def homePage(request):

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'SignIn' in request.POST:
        sign_in_detail = SignInForm(request.POST)
        if sign_in_detail.is_valid():
            return render(request, "index2.html",{})
    elif request.method == 'POST' and 'SendMessage' in request.POST:
        message_detail = DropUsaMessage(request.POST)
        if message_detail.is_valid():
            return render(request, "index.html",{})
    else:
        sign_in_detail = SignInForm()
        message_detail = DropUsaMessage()

    context={
        "form":sign_in_detail,
        "forms":message_detail
            }
    return render(request, "index.html",context)
```

index.html

```
<div class="container contact-form">
              <form method="post">
                      <h3>Drop Us a Message</h3>


                              {% csrf_token %}
                              {{ forms }}<br><br>
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <input type="submit" name="SendMessage" class="btnContact" value="Send Message" />
                              </div>



              </form>
      </div>
```

```
<div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <img src="{% static 'img/sampleImage.jpg' %}" width="100%" height="100%" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <form method="POST">
              {% csrf_token %}
              {{ form }}
              <div class="form-check">
                  <span class="fpswd">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
              </div>
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="SignIn">Submit</button>
            </form>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

app/forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.core import validators

class SignInForm(forms.Form):
    email=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": 'form-control',"placeholder":'Enter E-mail',"id": 'exampleInputEmail1'}))
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Enter Password',"id":'exampleInputPassword1'}))

class DropUsaMessage(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Your Name'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={"class": 'form-control',"placeholder":'Your E-mail',"id": 'exampleInputEmail1'}))
    phone = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Your Phone Number'}))
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={"class":'form-control',"placeholder":'Type Your Message',"style":'width:100%; height: 150px'}))
```

Expected Result:
After filling up the contact us form the field will be there.
Actual result:
there is no field in Contact us(except Send Message button) and no field in SignInForm(no e-mail and no password).

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the code flow and you'll notice that in the case of a POST request and "SignIn" in the post, you return the rendered "index2.html" template without any context (`form` and `forms` will be undefined in your template). Idem for the other case:

```
return render(request, "index2.html", {})  # empty context
```

Worse, if the form posted is not valid, you'll notice you only define one for the forms and not the other one, so when the code execution reaches the line `context = {"form": ..., "forms": ...}`, one of them will be undefined and your view will "crash", return a 500 error.

```
context = {'form': sign_in_detail,  # sign_in_detail never defined for second "if"
           'forms': message_detail}  # message_detail never define for first "if"
```

In general, when a `POST` is successful, you should **always** redirect to another view (or the same view). That's the internet convention, in order to avoid page reload issues that would resubmit the same data. Do this:

```
return redirect('home')  # or whatever your homepage url pattern is called
```

Also, it would make more sense to post your forms to different views (change the `action` attribute of each of your `<form>` tags) so you can process them in separate views which is cleaner code:

```
<form action="{% url 'create_message' %}" method="post">
```

Comment: but after that how can I link the multiple views to one url

Comment: Ok, then don't if you really need all of this to be in one page. Just make sure you always define both forms in all use cases.